# Opening custom extension file in android

Tags: android, file

I have created an app using which i wrote a file in sd card with .dtl extension.  Now i want whenever user clicks on my file it should get opened in my app like some .docx or .pdf file opens in word or adobe reader

Answer (score 0):

Read this articles: [Intents and Intent Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), [Data element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html).

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity android:name="YourActivityToOpenFile">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\.dtl"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And in activity onCreate:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Uri uriToFile = intent.getData();
    }
```

Comment: <intent-filter> tag shows warning missing URL and when i am clicking on file it shows toast unable to find application to open this file

Comment: @VikashParashar You can just suppress this warning. Are you opening file from file manager or not? This intent filter will react only on "android.intent.action.VIEW" action.

Comment: To suppress: <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">

Comment: its not working..... whenever i click on file it shows toast unable to find application to open this file

Comment: Change path pattern to <data android:pathPattern=".*\.[d,D][t,T][l,L]"/>